# Cursor com PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Tenho aqui uma tabela de trâmite que ativa um *trigger* quando é gravado um novo trâmite. No meu caso, quando alguém gera um trâmite para uma requisição que foi devolvida o sistema deve "devolver" a quantidade de itens que foram solicitados nessa requisição para a tabela de itens.

Fiz um *trigger* aqui para isso e estou usando cursor. A parte do *trigger* que era pra devolver os itens não está funcionando. Alguém poderia como posso consertar isso?

```
       --Devclaração do cursor
         c_contrato_item                compras.contrato_requisicao_item%ROWTYPE;     

       --Trecho que era pra funcionar
       FOR c_contrato_item IN 
            SELECT ano, contrato, item, quantidade FROM compras.contrato_requisicao_item
              WHERE ano_requisicao = NEW.ano_requisicao AND requisicao = NEW.requisicao
       LOOP 
           UPDATE compras.contrato_item SET (quantidade_saldo) = ((quantidade_saldo + c_contrato_item.quantidade))
               WHERE ano = c_contrato_item.ano
                 AND contrato = c_contrato_item.contrato
                 AND item = c_contrato_item.item;
       END LOOP;
```

Comment: essa trigger é disparada na tabela compras.contrato_requisicao_item ?

Comment: Não, na tabela de trâmite. Quando gera o trâmite de requisição devolvida ela dispara

Comment: pode colocar o código todo da trigger?